# Python сортировка Шелла

Tags: python, алгоритм, сортировка

У меня задание реализовать сортировку Шелла используя эмпирическую последовательность Марцина Циура. Оно сделано. Но есть одна проблема, когда я считаю количество перестановок то оно выдает всегда одинаковые числа для разного размера массива. Например есть массив рандомный размером `N` и такого же размера только статический и упорядоченный, то программа выдает кол-во перестановок для обоих массивов одинаковую, хотя кол-во сравнений разное ведь к примеру массив упорядоченный он уже есть отсортированный, а это значит что престановок должно быть `0`. Как решить проблему с подсчетом перестановок?

Собственно вот мой код(я брал только одну размерность что бы не было много кода)

```
from time import clock
from random import randint

LIST_SIZE1 = 10
LIST_SIZE2 = 100
LIST_SIZE3 = 1000
LIST_SIZE4 = 5000
LIST_SIZE5 = 200
LIST_SIZE6 = 300
LIST_SIZE7 = 400

def time_fn(to_call,param):
    start = clock()
    result = to_call(param)
    d_time = clock()-start;
    return d_time,result

def areEqual(a,b):
    return True if a==b else False

def run_test(to_test,test_with):
    time,value = time_fn(to_test,test_with)
    return [time,"OK"] if value==t_sorted else [time,"FAIL"]

def shell_sort(to_sort):
    gaps = [701,301,132,57,23,10,4,1]
    for gap in gaps:
        count_compariont = 0
        count = 0
        i = gap
        while i <= len(to_sort)-1:
            hole = to_sort[i]
            j = i
            count += 1
            while j>=gap and to_sort[j-gap] > hole:
                to_sort[j] = to_sort[j-gap]
                j-=gap
                count_compariont += 1
            to_sort[j] = hole
            i+=gap

    print("Counter of permutations ", count)
    print("Counter of comparison  ", count_compariont)
    return to_sort

"""Output"""
print("Testing ", " sorting algorithm with a ", LIST_SIZE4, " element list...")
print("Generating and sorting test values...")
test = [randint(-100,100) for i in range(LIST_SIZE4)]
t_sorted = shell_sort(test)
sorting4 = t_sorted
print("RUNNING TESTS...")
print("Shell sort:     ", run_test(shell_sort,test))

print("\n")

print("Array constant ")
print("Testing ", " sorting algorithm with a ", LIST_SIZE4, " element list...")
print("Generating and sorting test values...")
test1 = []
test1 = [i for i in range(LIST_SIZE4)]
t_sorted = shell_sort(test1)
#print("SSSSSSSSS ", t_sorted)
sorting1 = t_sorted
#The tests
print("RUNNING TESTS...")
print("Shell sort:     ", run_test(shell_sort,test1))

print("\n")
```

А вот результат

```
Testing   sorting algorithm with a  5000  element list...
Generating and sorting test values...
Counter of permutations  4999
Counter of comparison   4480801
RUNNING TESTS...
Counter of permutations  4999
Counter of comparison   0
Shell sort:      [0.005307999999999868, 'OK']


Array constant 
Testing   sorting algorithm with a  5000  element list...
Generating and sorting test values...
Counter of permutations  4999
Counter of comparison   0
RUNNING TESTS...
Counter of permutations  4999
Counter of comparison   0
Shell sort:      [0.005185999999999691, 'OK']
```

Answer (score 1):

Оба счетчика обнуляются **на каждом** новом значении gap, т.е. финальный вывод относится только к проходу с gap=1

Поэтому немудрено, что для Len=5000 выводится Counter of permutations  4999.

Да и считает этот счетчик вовсе не какие-то "permutations", а проходы по гребенке в массиве.

Вот счетчик с не менее загадочным названием `count_compariont` подсчитывает полуобмены (сдвиги элемента к финальной позиции)

Comment: а как мне тогда подсчитывать количество проходов?

Comment: Обнуление счетчиков вынести перед for. Количество проходов не зависит от данных, только от размера массива и выбранной последовательности шагов. Вот количество обменов будет варьироваться - оно так и есть: 4480801 и 0

Comment: а количество сравнений будет таким же как и количество обменов?

Comment: нет, больше - не все сравнения вызывают обмены